# How to use reactive search to achieve 'Load More' function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a searching page with Reactive search, and when users scroll the search results to the bottom, they can find a "Load More" button, by clicking it, the next page will be loaded. I found that in the document, there is a callback function called "handleLoadMore()", but I don't know how to use it.

The code I wrote is just like this.

```html
<ReactiveList
  className={classes.content}
  dataField={"description"}
  componentId={"SearchResult"}
  react={{ and: ["DataSearch"] }}
  pagination={false}
  scrollOnChange={true}
  stream={true}
  showResultStats={true}
  renderResultStats={stats => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p className={classes.stats}>
          {stats.numberOfResults} results available based on your location
        </p>
        <img
          className={classes.logo_color}
          src={require("../../images/logo-color.png")}
          alt="logo-color"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }}
  paginationAt="bottom"
  size={12}
  infiniteScroll={true}
  loader="Loading Results.."
>
  {({ data, handleLoadMore }) => {
    return (
      <ResultCardsWrapper className={classes.cardsWrapper}>
        {data.map((element, index) => {
          console.log(data);
          return (
            <ResultCard className={classes.card} key={index} target={"_self"}>
              <Link
                className={classes.wrapper}
                to={`/shop/${element._index}/${element._id}`}
              >
                <ResultCard.Image
                  className={classes.image}
                  src={getLogo(element.logo)}
                />
                <ResultCard.Title className={classes.title}>
                  {element.title}
                  <div className={classes.shopIcons}>
                    {console.log(element.opening_hour[curDay].open)}
                    {curTime <= element.opening_hour[curDay].close &&
                    curTime >= element.opening_hour[curDay].open ? (
                      <img
                        src={require("../../images/Icon ionic-md-time.svg")}
                        alt="open"
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <img
                        src={require("../../images/Icon ionic-md-time-closed.svg")}
                        alt="open"
                      />
                    )}
                    <img
                      src={require("../../images/Icon material-local-offer.svg")}
                      alt="offer"
                    />
                  </div>
                </ResultCard.Title>
              </Link>
            </ResultCard>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={handleLoadMore}>Load More</button>
      </ResultCardsWrapper>
    );
  }}
</ReactiveList>;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can replace the handleLoadMore to loadMore, it works for me.